# How can I set Hot Corners shortcut to minimize all applications?

Tags: settings, show-desktop

I remember that I used this trick a while ago, but can't remember the command I've used. Basically, I've set Hot Corner shortcut to "Execute custom command", and then typed in the command similar to `minimize-all` or `show-all` or something like that (neither one of those is the correct one). Can someone suggest what is the correct command for minimizing all the applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used commands you mentioned. but here is the solution for what you are asking.

first you need to install wmctrl.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

then here is the command for minimize.

```
wmctrl -k on
```

this one is for restore all windows.

```
wmctrl -k off
```

hope this will solve your problem. cheers!!

Comment: Its working, Well Done- good work =)

Answer (score 0):

```
show-desktop
```

Is what I use in hot corners in Luna--It worked in Freya too but updates apparently killed it.

Comment: Have you tried this on _freya_, sorry, its not working on my system

Comment: Yeah, not working here, either... But I think that that's the command I've used, too, since I was on Luna, too, when I used it...

Comment: You guys are right. I went back and checked on Freya's progress this AM and it's not working for Freya anymore. I guess one of the updates killed it.

Comment: yeah, not working :(