# How to minimize from active corners

Tags: desktop, command-line, hot-corners, minimize

I want to minimize a window through the active corners I only see that it can be done by means of a customized command, does anyone know what it would be? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: perhaps this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/how-can-i-set-hot-corners-shortcut-to-minimize-all-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the keyboard shortcut to something like super+alt+h

Then install `xdotool`

Then at the hot corner settings select the execute command and put in 
`xdotool` key <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

This is how I'm doing it

**Edit:** I found that `xdotool` actually has this built-in `xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize` is much easier then above. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I used this method by installing wmctrl:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Then write the following command of the active corner:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

It worked for me...